# duplicate extension "woff", content type: "font/woff2", previous content type: "font/woff" in /etc/nginx/mime.types

Tags: nginx

After the latest Nginx update (currently nginx/1.21.6), the following warning started to appear when I do a `nginx -t`:

> nginx: [warn] duplicate extension "woff", content type: "font/woff2", previous content type: "font/woff" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:29

The same issue is happening on all my servers, with Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 + latest nginx mainline

I never edited the `mime.types` files, which has the following:

```
types {
    [...]
    font/woff                             woff;
    font/woff2                            woff;
}
```

From what I understand it doesn't like these two lines having the same value, but which one should I delete?

Comment: make this change `error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found out where the issue was, If you have the same issue you're probably using the `ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline` repository, and you have:

```
font/woff                             woff;
font/woff2                            woff;
```

Instead of:

```
font/woff                                        woff;
font/woff2                                       woff2;
```

See the file on the [nginx/nginx master branch](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/67d2a9541826ecd5db97d604f23460210fd3e517/conf/mime.types) for reference.

Comment: what do you suggest instead `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline` ?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev just manually edit the `/etc/nginx/mime.types` file and add the missing `2`. The only problem is that with updates it may ask you which version to keep, you should always install the maintainer version and then add the 2 again if missing. I already reported the issue, hope he will fix